# How do i get cURL to use https

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, https

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. cURL's installed but does not include HTTPS as a protocol that it will use.

For example:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

gives me this:

```
curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

Checking curl -V results in:

```
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile
```

HTTPS is missing from that list... so, how do I install cURL with support for HTTPS?

Oh, and `sudo apt-get install curl` is what I did to install it in the first place.

Comment: Why was this a bad question / downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your curl version wasn't compiled with SSL support.  It's actually a flag that is passed during the config phase:

`./configure --with-ssl`

The quickest and most complete way is to download the [curl sources](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and [compile it yourself](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) with the `--with-ssl` flag.  This will also ensure that your curl and SSL libraries won't be vulnerable to any of the nasty, known vulnerabilities as well.  There are workarounds for using insecure versions of SSL but of course that's not recommended.

Comment: Thx! That's it. Do you know why Aptitude doesn't give me a version with HTTPS?

Comment: I think it's to bring attention to the security vulnerabilities that have swept the Internet lately (like Heartbleed).  SSLv2 has has it's fair share of security issues.  Here are some more issues: http://superuser.com/questions/246074/ssl-whats-the-reason-for-disabling-ssl-v2-support.  By disabling it it forces the user to compile new with updated libraries so that some of these issues go away.

Comment: In fact curl has an `--insecure` flag that you can pass when running it that will force it to use SSLv2 even though it considers v2 as insecure (for good reason).  you didn't have to pass the ssl config flags for the latest version because it probably found SSLv3 support on your system and compiled in SSL support for that version.  So it's not apt that disables it - it was a choice of curl package maintainers.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know why using Aptitude installs a version without support for HTTPS but building from scratch did the trick:

```
git clone https://github.com/bagder/curl.git
sudo apt-get build-dep curl
cd curl
./buildconf
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Now `curl -V` yields

```
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Oh and the reason I needed this in the first place is because NVM gave me N/A when trying to download a version of Node or get a listing of available versions with nvm ls-remote. That was caused by cURL not working for HTTPS requests.

Comment: This does not work.  I get: remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/badger/curl.git/' not found

Comment: @rf_wilson This is years old, but note that the user is 'bagder', not 'badger'.

Comment: `sudo apt-get build-dep curl` reports 'Unable to find a source package for curl' - why is that even needed?

Comment: Note that your version of libcurl may be older than the curl version. In that case determine it with `apt list --installed libcurl\*` and then checkout the respective `curl-X_Y_Z` tag before building.

Answer (score -1):

There are some possibilities that your linux machine does not have libssl libraries. And curl will not configure OpenSSL because of this and the https will not be enabled.

First run the command:

`apt-get install libssl-dev`

After this run:

`./configure --with-ssl`

This worked for me