# How to solve this ? Curl Error : Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: libcurl

I was looking everywhere how to solve this problem and nothing.

I am using Centos 6 VPS.    Thanks

Comment: Please share more details. Is this in any way related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

Your libcurl is built without ssl support.
e.g. --without-ssl

[libcurl FAQ](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_1_SSL_is_disabled_https)

Comment: You will have to build the libcurl using the correct switch. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782556/how-do-i-get-curl-to-use-https and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636536/install-curl-with-openssl

Answer (score 0):

As [@Icarus3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919896/icarus3) mentioned, make sure SSL feature is enabled.

```
$ curl --version
```

See [`curl/CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt).

```
if(WIN32 OR CURL_USE_SECTRANSP OR CURL_USE_SCHANNEL OR CURL_USE_MBEDTLS OR CURL_USE_NSS OR CURL_USE_WOLFSSL)
  set(openssl_default OFF)
endif()
```

If you are using CMake to build curl, you can use the following command.

```
$ cmake -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
        -D CURL_USE_SCHANNEL=ON \
        -D CURL_STATIC_CRT=ON ..
```

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu, you may install the development package, which is libssl-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

It works for me.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it