# Manual install of curl can't find openssl

Tags: ssl, curl, centos

My system (Centos7) install of curl doesn't support https. So I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782556/how-do-i-get-curl-to-use-https) downloaded from [source](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and [installed myself](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html), using the `./configure --with-ssl` option.

I got the following warning while configuring:

```
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl... no
checking OpenSSL linking with -ldl and -lpthread... no
checking for ssl_version in -laxtls... no
configure: WARNING: SSL disabled, you will not be able to use HTTPS, FTPS, NTLM and more.
configure: WARNING: Use --with-ssl, --with-gnutls, --with-polarssl, --with-cyassl, --with-nss, --with-axtls, --with-winssl, or --with-darwinssl to address this.
```

As a result, my curl build does not support https.

Open SSL is installed on my system:

```
[user@server curl-7.61.0]$ which openssl
/usr/bin/openssl
```

How can I get my curl install to find openssl and support HTTPS?

Comment: Do you have `openssl-devel` ,`openssl-devel`,`openssl-libs` packages installed? Not sure if this will help or not..  You might want to consider using the same version of `curl` that ships with the CentOS 7.x release when building your own..

Comment: @GoinOff To your first point, devel is not intalled, but libs is. I have another CentOS7 server with the same exact version and curl setup, but with https supported. That one also has the same openssl and -libs but not devel installed.

Comment: @GoinOff yes, installing openssl-devel fixed this. Post an answer if you want the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing `openssl-devel`. Development (-devel) packages are usually needed when building from source.